# Pointer Address/Dereferencing operator

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int y = 4; //This is a variable stored in the stack
  printf("\n Address of variable y is :%p\n", &y); // This is the address of the variable  y
  int *addressOfVariable = &y; //This is a pointer variable, a P.V stores the memory address of a variable
  //Read the value stored in a memory address
  int memoryValue = *addressOfVariable; //* is a dereference operator, it reads the value stored in a memory address and stores it in another variable
  //Update the value stored in the memory address
  *addressOfVariable = 10;
  _getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this code? As is clear from the comments, I am just trying to implement the use of pointers and pointers variables. Among the other errors, I am getting a "Illegal Indirection error" in the (*addressOfVariable=10) code.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: Apart from `conio.h`/`_getch` compiles cleanly for me. What's your compiler/environment?

Comment: Works fine for me, too. If I print `y` at the end it shows `10`.

Comment: I'm using MS Visual Studio 2012 on Windows. I'm also getting a 'addressOfVariable undeclared identifier' error. No idea why!

Comment: It will at the beginning of the block variable declaration If you're using MSVC

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Could you please elaborate a bit further?

Comment: You have to write at the beginning of the block declaration of a variable in C89.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That makes no sense.[/trying to understand what exactly did you mean]

Comment: @self @user2981518: @BLUEPIXY meant that MSVC only allows C89/C90 code, where statements and variable declarations cannot be mixed. All variable declarations inside a function body must be at the start of a new scope (immediately after the `{` and before its matching `}`). Declare all of the variables at the start of the function body, and MSVC will compile the code.

Comment: I feel I should add that since MSVC is a C++ compiler, you are better off finding a C compiler to compile your code. Otherwise you may run into more problems like this in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here with pointer or dereferencing operator (`*`). It seems that you are not compiling your code in C99 mode. In C89 mixed type declarations are not allowed.

EDIT: As OP said in his comment that he is using MS Visual Studio 2012, MSVC does't support C99 (basically it is a C++ compiler). You can't compile your code in C99 mode. Now declare all the variables in the beginning of the code like C89;

```
int y=4;
int *addressOfVariable=&y;
int memoryValue=*addressOfVariable; 
....
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    int y=4;
    int *addressOfVariable=&y;
    int memoryValue=*addressOfVariable;
    printf("\n Address of variable y is :%p\n",&y);
    *addressOfVariable=10;
    _getch();
```

Comment: I won't down vote, but I hope you realise this isn't a complete answer. It gives the correct code without explaining why it is correct compared to the code in the question.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I have already described.
but he did not understand.
So shows the specific code.

Comment: I do not know think of Microsoft. Why C89 in 2013?

Comment: MSVC is a C++ compiler. Why should it support C99 aside from what is required by the C++11 standard?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune C and C++ are different languages​​.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Which is my main point: why do we not discourage the usage of C++ compilers when compiling C code when we know they are very different languages?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I would because thinks that it has encountered it upward compatible. But It differ.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Without any explanation, this answer simply isn't helpful.